# What is the optimal JOIN approach here?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Here are two queries that return the same resultset, but which is the optimal statement or doesn't it matter?

```
SELECT A.id, B.somefield FROM (
   SELECT id from table1
   UNION
   SELECT id from table2
) A LEFT JOIN table3 B on A.id = B.id
```

or

```
SELECT A.id, B.somefield FROM table1 A LEFT JOIN table3 B on A.id = B.id
UNION
SELECT A.id, B.somefield FROM table2 B LEFT JOIN table3 B on A.id = B.id
```

I realise I could pump them full of data and run some tests, but I am as much interested in the 'why' if one is faster? (I am using postgresql, in case it influences things).

Thanks.

Comment: As a tangential point, if you can't get duplicates id values between table1 and table2, `UNION ALL` will be faster than a plain `UNION`, since it won't need to check for duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, first off, `id` in the select list is ambiguous; do we want `A.id` or `B.id`?

Second, assuming id is an indexed field in all tables, de-duping and joining are both NlogM operations, where N is the number of rows on the "left" side and M the number of rows on the "right" side. For each row in N, a matching row in M must be found or not found (when joining, rows found in M are included in the results; when unioning, rows found in M are excluded). This would mean that minimizing the cardinality of the left side will give the greatest performance.

So, the complexity of either query pretty much depends on how many shared IDs there are between table 1 and table 2. With zero commonality (no rows IDs the same) and 100 rows per table, the first query will perform one 100log100 union and then a 200log100 join, and the second query will perform two 100log100 joins and then a 100log100 union, which would execute in equivalent time. However, with 100% commonality (every row in table 1 is also in 2), the first query will perform a 100log100 union, then a 100log100 join (as the UNION of 1 and 2 would be equivalent to table 1), while the second query will still perform two 100log100 joins and a 100log100 union. As the worst-cases are the same but the best-case of query 1 is two-thirds that of query 2, I'd go for query 1.

However, as the commenter said, if you don't expect any dupes, a UNION ALL will perform better in both queries. The result of a UNION ALL of A and B is A+B, which is bound only by the access time of each set (which I haven't been considering). By not expecting dupes, both of the queries can be cut to the best-case performance of the first query.

Comment: Thanks - I found this really useful and actually somewhat fascinating (sad I know!)

Answer (score 3):

The execution plan for using `UNION` first shows a lot less steps, unfortunately execution plans are not everything, there is also table scans, logical reads, CPU usage so this is not the be all and end all of it and it largely depends on your data and your indicies.

With dupes the first query should perform better because the removal of duplicates by the `UNION` takes place before the join resulting in a lower number of table scans on table 3. If there are no duplicates in table1 and table2 then there should be no difference.

This can be demonstrated with some sample data. All my samples use the folling 5 tables (T4 and T5 are simply to dump the output into so you don't have to scroll miles down the page on SQL fiddle to see the execution plans)

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE T2 (ID INT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE T3 (FK INT NOT NULL, SomeValue VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE T4 (ID INT NOT NULL, SomeValue VARCHAR(10) NULL);
CREATE TABLE T5 (ID INT NOT NULL, SomeValue VARCHAR(10) NULL);
```

And all use the following to test (also done in reverse to elimate any query plan caching):

```
INSERT INTO T4
SELECT  ID, SomeValue
FROM    T1
        LEFT JOIN T3
            ON ID = FK
UNION 
SELECT  ID, SomeValue
FROM    T2
        LEFT JOIN T3
            ON ID = FK;

INSERT INTO T5
SELECT  ID, SomeValue
FROM    (   SELECT  ID
            FROM    T1
            UNION
            SELECT  ID
            FROM    T2
        ) T
        LEFT JOIN T3
            ON ID = FK;
```

**Example 1 - T1 contains rows that are also in T2**

```
INSERT INTO T1 (ID)
SELECT  *
FROM    GENERATE_SERIES(0, 40000);

INSERT INTO T2 (ID)
SELECT  *
FROM    GENERATE_SERIES(20000, 60000);

INSERT INTO T3 (FK, SomeValue)
SELECT  *, 'VALUE'
FROM    GENERATE_SERIES(10000, 50000);
```

[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/ccb42/1) shows that Inserting to T4 (`UNION` before `JOIN`) performs better. I have run this 25 times with insert to T4 running faster on 22 of these times. There is not enough data to remove server load from the equation so it is as expected that there are some anomolies. The order of the insert is reversed in [this example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/ccb42/2), again similar results were seen.

**Example 2 - No duplicates in table1 and table2**

```
INSERT INTO T1 (ID)
SELECT  *
FROM    GENERATE_SERIES(0, 30000);

INSERT INTO T2 (ID)
SELECT  *
FROM    GENERATE_SERIES(30001, 60000);

INSERT INTO T3 (FK, SomeValue)
SELECT  *, 'VALUE'
FROM    GENERATE_SERIES(10000, 50000);
```

In this example the execution times are much closer to each other and frequently switch between which method performs faster.

[Sample Data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/831d4/2)

[Sample Data 2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/831d4/1)

Finally, to reiterate the point that has already been made, if you are not expecting dupes/don't care about dupes then `UNION ALL` will improve performance, but since with no dupes the performance should be largely similar with both methods this is should improve both methods in equal measure. I have not tested this but it should not be a massive task to alter the test data I have used to check this.

**EDIT**

I have just tried the queries on SQL Fiddle and they show significantly more variance than they did on my local machine, so take these examples with a pinch of salt and do your tests on your own server, it is a lot easier to create a fair testing environment!

Comment: FYI - performance testing based on actual execution times on sql fiddle is pretty limited and of little value.  Too many factors (CPU load, OS configuration, hardware setup, limited data size, etc...) will be different from sql fiddle then would be on a real env.  The only thing that I would suggest you use SQL fiddle for, regarding performance, is comparing execution plans.

Comment: @Gareth thanks for all your effort - ! marked you up, but opted for Keith's answer as I felt it really examined the core math behind what occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT A.id, ...` for each query and compare the results. They might be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Run postgres' [EXPLAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html) for each query and have a look at the execution cost.

Answer (score 0):

The query below generates a different query plan than the two by @GarethD, but perform about the same (after adding the primary keys):

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH ttt AS (
    SELECT COALESCE(t1.id,t2.id) AS id
        FROM    t1
        FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    )   
INSERT INTO t6 (id, somevalue)
SELECT tx.id AS id
    , t3.somevalue AS somevalue
FROM ttt tx
LEFT JOIN t3 ON tx.id = t3.fk
        ;
```

NOTE: in the query plan the COALESCE() function is absent, so it is actually treated as an operator (which is Good):

```
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Insert on t6  (cost=3761.65..5761.69 rows=40001 width=10) (actual time=1643.429..1643.429 rows=0 loops=1)
   CTE ttt
     ->  Hash Full Join  (cost=1004.80..2488.62 rows=40001 width=8) (actual time=129.768..399.898 rows=60001 loops=1)
           Hash Cond: (t1.id = t2.id)
           ->  Seq Scan on t1  (cost=0.00..557.01 rows=40001 width=4) (actual time=0.008..60.693 rows=40001 loops=1)
           ->  Hash  (cost=533.80..533.80 rows=37680 width=4) (actual time=129.737..129.737 rows=40001 loops=1)
                 Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 938kB
                 ->  Seq Scan on t2  (cost=0.00..533.80 rows=37680 width=4) (actual time=0.016..62.236 rows=40001 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1273.02..3273.06 rows=40001 width=10) (actual time=265.672..999.408 rows=60001 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (tx.id = t3.fk)
         ->  CTE Scan on ttt tx  (cost=0.00..800.02 rows=40001 width=4) (actual time=129.776..603.317 rows=60001 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=597.01..597.01 rows=40001 width=10) (actual time=135.854..135.854 rows=40001 loops=1)
               Buckets: 4096  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 627kB
               ->  Seq Scan on t3  (cost=0.00..597.01 rows=40001 width=10) (actual time=0.009..66.008 rows=40001 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 1644.480 ms
```

With better tuning (less work_mem, to forced disk-based execution, and lower random_page_cost to facilitate index usage) the plan even becomes better:

```
SET work_mem = 64;
SET random_page_cost = 2.1;
SET seq_page_cost = 2;


                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Insert on t6  (cost=4404.54..6654.58 rows=40001 width=10) (actual time=1573.465..1573.465 rows=0 loops=1)
   CTE ttt
     ->  Merge Full Join  (cost=0.00..2758.52 rows=40001 width=8) (actual time=0.048..348.906 rows=60001 loops=1)
           Merge Cond: (t1.id = t2.id)
           ->  Index Scan using t1_pkey on t1  (cost=0.00..1103.37 rows=40001 width=4) (actual time=0.022..67.840 rows=40001 loops=1)
           ->  Index Scan using t2_pkey on t2  (cost=0.00..1084.15 rows=37680 width=4) (actual time=0.018..68.583 rows=40001 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1646.02..3896.06 rows=40001 width=10) (actual time=170.840..957.899 rows=60001 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (tx.id = t3.fk)
         ->  CTE Scan on ttt tx  (cost=0.00..800.02 rows=40001 width=4) (actual time=0.055..544.544 rows=60001 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=794.01..794.01 rows=40001 width=10) (actual time=170.130..170.130 rows=40001 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 32  Memory Usage: 42kB
               ->  Seq Scan on t3  (cost=0.00..794.01 rows=40001 width=10) (actual time=0.009..79.751 rows=40001 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 1574.108 ms
(13 rows)
```